# How can I solve the error "Kernel Power EventID 41"?

Tags: operating-systems

My laptop started doing this recently

It does this sometimes when I wake it from sleep /standby. It just restarts.

And sometimes when I turn it on (from having it properly shut down the day before).

In both cases the device restarts (since the uptime resets) and a kernel power error gets logged in the event viewer under "critical errors". Its description says:

*The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.*

It does this with a frequency of 1 time every 24 hrs maybe

There are also two other critical errors alongside this one. a "DriverFrameworks-UserMode" with EventID: 10110 , its description says: *A problem has occurred with one or more user-mode drivers and the hosting process has been terminated. This may temporarily interrupt your ability to access the devices.*

and another "DriverFrameworks-UserMode" with EventID: 10111 its description says: *The device Intel(R) Dynamic Tuning Technology Device Extension Component (location (unknown)) is offline due to a user-mode driver crash. Windows will attempt to restart the device 5 more times. Please contact the device manufacturer for more information about this problem.*

Don't know if these two additional critical errors are related to the Kernel Power one. There have been multiple instances of these ones, more than the kernel power one.

**What can I do?**

I really don't want this to be a hardware problem since I never treated this laptop rough or anything like that, I'm always delicate with stuff, with storage, cleaning, mantaining and similar.

I recently also did a clean reinstall of Windows 11 since I tried to go back to a previous restore point for a totally different reason (the error id 41 was already happening before) , but the process froze, the OS bricked and had to reinstall. This solved the other reason, not the kernel power error.

They say it's usually related to a faulty or failing AC adapter, but mine is working fine, doesn't even get too hot, and doesn't even make noise. You'd have to put your ear on it to actually hear a very faint buzzing, that is, as far as I know, normal for every electrical device since it's the current passing through.

I can't provide logs, since I can't find them

So basically this error doesn't dump anything, neither a minidump nor a normal one, which is weird since "write an event to the system log" is turned on in "advanced system settings". I haven't done any major settings modification, everything is set to default except I have windows in dark mode except of light. But that's all, I leave everything as default to avoid this kind of bullcrap and rule "dumb user changes" out.

I could have tried some advanced troubleshooting if only I could find these damn dumps. But I can't find them in the location they're supposed to be.

I don't even wanna try asking this on microsoft answers because they're just gonna say run dism or chkdisk and other useless stuff like that.

Also I've found, using the reliability monitor in control panel, that this problem is also reported there under critical events as *Windows was not properly shut down* and a description: *The previous system shutdown at 19:48:33 on ‎09/‎08/‎2023 was unexpected*. And nothing more

but there's another entry (under critical events) reported as: *Intel(R) Innovation Platform Framework Service Container*, for which it gives me more details, don't know if it's related , this:

Source

Intel(R) Innovation Platform Framework Service Container

Summary

Stopped working

Date

‎10.‎8.‎23 11:50 AM

Status

Report sent

Description

Faulting Application Path: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\dtt_sw.inf_amd64_4a0efaf978352e5b\ipfsvc.exe

Problem signature

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH

Application Name: ipfsvc.exe

Application Version: 1.0.11101.30293

Application Timestamp: 63507449

Fault Module Name: ipfipc.dll

Fault Module Version: 1.0.10702.25133

Fault Module Timestamp: 61b9186d

Exception Code: c0000005

Exception Offset: 000000000000c494

OS Version: 10.0.22621.2.0.0.768.101

Locale ID: 2057

Additional Information 1: 9100

Additional Information 2: 9100dcf2fc06c8d305d4e5691e97f478

Additional Information 3: 7c8e

Additional Information 4: 7c8e3e323f147bb42335bbeea108db63

Extra information about the problem

Bucket ID: 5fbe5206484318817f361371cc1af922 (2249006443394693410)

​

the OS is Win11 22h2

​